# How to add data to existing database in my android app?

Tags: android, database, web-services, sqlite, android-studio

We created an application with web service. Our data type are json. And android app can get datas from ip address server.
 But they doesnt appear in database. How can we fix it? Our codes are below.

DatabaseHelper Class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        String DB_PATH = null;
        private static String DB_NAME = "bosdata.db";
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        private final Context myContext;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DB_NAME, null, 10);
            this.myContext = context;
           this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
            //Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
        }
    //
    //
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
            } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (newVersion > oldVersion)
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }

        public ArrayList<Liste_Model> get_All_Parts() {
            openDataBase();
            ArrayList<Liste_Model> arr = new ArrayList<Liste_Model>();


            Cursor c = myDataBase.query("db4OptimumOptimumSiraliRota", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToNext()) {
                    do {
                        Liste_Model model = new Liste_Model();
                        model.setResim_No(c.getString(0));
                        model.setKasa_Yeri(c.getString(1));
                        model.setAraba_Bolme_Yeri(c.getString(2));
                        arr.add(model);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            c.close();
            myDataBase.close();
            return arr;
        }

        public void add_SiraliListe(Liste_Model model) {
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            openDataBase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("ResimNo", model.getResim_No().toString());
            values.put("KasaYeri", model.getKasa_Yeri().toString());
            values.put("ArabaBolmeYeri", model.getAraba_Bolme_Yeri().toString());
            myDataBase.insertOrThrow("db4OptimumOptimumSiraliRota", null, values);


            myDataBase.close();
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button bSorgula;
    String resimno= "";
    String kasayeri = "";
    String arababolmeyeri = "";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bSorgula = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSorgula);
        bSorgula.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new myAsyncTask("Yükleniyor").execute();
    }

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String modalMesaj;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        public myAsyncTask(String mMesaj) {
            this.modalMesaj = mMesaj;
            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage(modalMesaj);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            String url = "http://192.168.163.1:8097/Products.aspx";

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    String result = convertStreamToString(instream);

                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
                    List<String> Liste_Model = new ArrayList<String>();
                    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                        Liste_Model.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ResimNo"));
                        Liste_Model.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("KasaYeri"));
                        Liste_Model.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArabaBolmeYeri"));

                        Liste_Model model = new Liste_Model();

                        try {
                            databaseHelper.createDataBase();
                            model.setResim_No(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ResimNo"));
                            model.setKasa_Yeri(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("KasaYeri"));
                            model.setAraba_Bolme_Yeri(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ArabaBolmeYeri"));

                            databaseHelper.add_SiraliListe(model);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }



                    instream.close();
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Mesaj(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Mesaj(e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Mesaj(e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void str) {

            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();


        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line ;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void Mesaj(String s) {

        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Liste Model Class

```
public class Liste_Model {
    private String Resim_No;
    private String Kasa_Yeri;
    private String Araba_Bolme_Yeri;

    public String getResim_No() {
        return Resim_No;
    }

    public void setResim_No(String resim_No) {
        Resim_No = resim_No;
    }

    public String getKasa_Yeri() {
        return Kasa_Yeri;
    }

    public void setKasa_Yeri(String kasa_Yeri) {
        Kasa_Yeri = kasa_Yeri;
    }

    public String getAraba_Bolme_Yeri() {
        return Araba_Bolme_Yeri;
    }

    public void setAraba_Bolme_Yeri(String araba_Bolme_Yeri) {
        Araba_Bolme_Yeri = araba_Bolme_Yeri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explaining your code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you manually create path to your database? You should instead use your DatabaseHelper's `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` methods as it is explained in [official manual](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). And write more detailed information why do you think it is not put into database, maybe you just can't read it correctly? Is there any error or crash? But first try to rewrite your code as it is given in official documentation.

Comment: We are developing an application for Sony-Smart EyeGlass and if we use manuel database like we do, we always have to run the android studio again and again. But we don't want to refresh the android studio all the time. Because, we will use the glass in industrial operations. Actually, can we get datas directly ip address server to android studio? I think it can help us.

Comment: @TuğçeAcar, I don't understand what is the problem then? You get Json Array from your IP address. Then you just need to parse this Json. Use this manual how to do this with [JsonReader class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)
Hope that's what you are looking for. And note, that JsonArray is surrounded by [ ], but Json Object by { }. Actually you can process all data without saving it into database. Just parse(read) json and do whatever you need. You can also save data in some ArrayList<MyClass>

Comment: Yes you are right. I will show the datas on the glass screen without saving.Thank you.

Comment: @TuğçeAcar, I am glad that it helped you. Don't want to look like selfish, but I am new on StackOverflow, so I need some reputation to be able to leave comments under questions. So I'll really appreciate if you put my answer as correct, of course, if it will help you. Best regards. Let me know if you have some issues with Json, will try to help you.